# Usage of <component> tags inside Blazor razor files

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

Is it possible to render `<component>` tags inside `.razor` files. I have a requirement where a static script needs to be rendered inside another Blazor component.  So, I have created the script tags using `BuildRenderTree` concept and tried to add the `<component>` tag with `render-mode` as `Static`. But, it won't render in the web page.

**ScriptRender.razor**

```
public class ScriptRender : ComponentBase
{
  [Parameter]
  public List<string> Source { get; set; }
  protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
  {
     base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
     foreach (var scriptPath in Source)
     {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "script");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "src", scriptPath);
        builder.CloseElement();
     }           
   }
}
```

**BlazorComponent.razor**

```
<component type="typeof(ScriptRender)" render-mode="Static"></component>
// Rest of component rendering logics
```

I know, the `<component>` tags can be used in the layout.cshtml pages. Isn't working in Blazor razor pages?

Comment: This resource might help you! https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16218

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component Tag Helper does not belong in Blazor. Blazor does not have the concept of tag helpers, but components, and thus you cannot embed it in a Blazor component. You can only use the component Tag Helper in .cshtml extension files. In the context of Blazor, the component Tag Helper is used in the _Host.cshtml file, which is actually a Razor Page that handle the initial request to a Blazor Server App, including the rendering of the Blazor app.